# How to get size and type of a file that is being uploaded with Symfony?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have an upload file field in my `newSuccess.php` template.

In my database there are fields for the size and the type of the file uploaded, currently **introduced manually**.

Is there any way to get the size(in KB) and the type of the file automatically and put them on the database?

Answer (score 0):

In the action code handling the form post after validating the form you can access these data through the sfValidatedFile class which has getSize() and getType() methods